# Changing columns position in attributes table using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, layers, features, qml

Well, I'm new to PyQGIS and I was creating a new shapefile and layer using some information from other layer.

I inserted the data that I wanted inside attributes table and styled it, but I wanted the table to follow my **feature position** and it's not working the way I want.

Here's what I want:

Ex: `TIPO_VIA |NOME_VIA | N_POLICI  | COMPLEMENTO | CODEPOSTAL | etc..`

Here's how it goes:

Ex: `CODEPOSTAL  | etc.. | TIPO_VIA |NOME_VIA | N_POLICIA  | COMPLEMENTO| etc..`

```
root = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot()
group = root.addGroup("RBAL_BYSAT_TEMP")
path = QgsProject.instance().readPath("./")
group_name = "RBAL_BYSAT_TEMP"
rbal_bysat_path = path + "/TEMP_SHAPE_FILE_FOLDER/"+group_name+".shp"

layerFields = QgsFields()
field_list = [QgsField("TIPO_VIA", QVariant.String),
            QgsField("NOME_VIA",  QVariant.String),
            QgsField("N_POLICIA", QVariant.Int),
            QgsField("COMPLEMENTO", QVariant.String),
            QgsField("CODEPOSTAL", QVariant.Int),
            QgsField("COMMUNE", QVariant.String),
            QgsField("INSEE", QVariant.String),
            QgsField("HEXACLE_N", QVariant.Int),
            QgsField("COORD_X", QVariant.Double),
            QgsField("COORD_Y", QVariant.Double),
            QgsField("PRECISION", QVariant.String),
            QgsField("BAL_LOG", QVariant.Int),
            QgsField("BAL_ENT", QVariant.Int),
            QgsField("BAL", QVariant.Int),
            QgsField("TIPO_CONEXAO", QVariant.String),
            QgsField("FOTO_MURO", QVariant.String),
            QgsField("FOTO_CAIXA", QVariant.String),
            QgsField("HPs_TOTAL", QVariant.Int),
            QgsField("NOVA_RUA", QVariant.String),
            QgsField("COMENTARIO", QVariant.String)]

for field in field_list:
    layerFields.append(field)


layer = iface.activeLayer()
rbal_france = layer.selectedFeatures()

feature_list = [] 
for feature in rbal_france:

    feat = QgsFeature(layerFields) 
    feat.setGeometry(feature.geometry())
    attr = feature.attributes()
    list = [ attr[4],attr[7], NULL,NULL, attr[0], NULL,attr[1],attr[6],attr[28],attr[29],attr[14], NULL, NULL,NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL]
    
    feat.setAttributes(list) 
    feature_list.append(feat)

writer_rbal = QgsVectorFileWriter(rbal_bysat_path, "UTF-8", layerFields, QgsWkbTypes.Point, QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem("EPSG:4326"), "ESRI Shapefile")
writer_rbal.addFeatures(feature_list)




layer_rbal = QgsVectorLayer(rbal_bysat_path, group_name , "ogr")

layer_rbal.startEditing()

layer_rbal.loadNamedStyle(path + "/TEMP_SHAPE_FILE_FOLDER/STYLE_QML/RBAL_BYSAT.qml")
layer_rbal.triggerRepaint()

layer_rbal.dataProvider().addFeatures(feature_list)

crs = layer_rbal.crs()
crs.createFromId(4326)
layer_rbal.setCrs(crs)

layer_rbal.commitChanges()

QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(layer_rbal,False)
group.insertChildNode(0, QgsLayerTreeLayer(layer_rbal))
```

Comment: Consider adding fields via the [`QgsDataProvider`](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsDataProvider.html), like it is shown here: https://anitagraser.com/pyqgis-101-introduction-to-qgis-python-programming-for-non-programmers/pyqgis101-creating-editing-a-new-vector-layer/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The order of the fields **must be** ordered in the qml file as in the second example. If you add the file `RBAL_BYSAT_TEMP.shp` to QGIS by drag-and-drop you will see that the order is as you want. Applying the qml to the layer changes the order of fields.

To solve the issue,

- sort the fields in the attribute table as you desire, save the style (using "Layer Properties > Style Button > Save Style...") as a new qml file and use that qml file for the layer in `loadNamedStyle` method.

Or

- remove `loadNamedStyle` line.